# Is it possible for an atom to contain multiple electrons in the same excited state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, laser, photonics

This question mostly stems from my quite rudimentary knowledge of laser physics. As far as I understand it, all the 3,4,..-level-systems regard the electrons being in more or less excited states. However, I very frequently hear that the atom itself is excited. This, for me, brings the question: Can the electrons of a laser medium (say Chromium in a ruby laser) be brought to a specific excited state independently from each other or is there a strict limit of 1,2,n excited electrons per atom?
Is an atom then called "excited" if at least one of its electrons are excited?

Please forgive the (maybe) naive question, but this has been a major roadblock to understanding lasers in detail for me being an engineer, not a physicist.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrons are Fermions, so the Pauli exclusion principle applies: Only one electron may exist in a given state.

Of course, there are ways to distinguish states such that many electrons in a gain medium may be excited. The same state on different atoms count as different states. Electrons with different spins (up vs down) count as being in different states, etc.